# Can Selenium Server run from remote network path?

Tags: java, windows-7, selenium

I am trying to run Selenium Server using a network path as follows:

```
java -jar "\\my-remote-computer-name\Software\selenium-server-2.5.0\selenium-server-standalone-2.5.0.jar"
```

and how can I avoid this exception:

```
Sep 6, 2011 11:15:48 AM org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher main
INFO: Launching a standalone server
11:15:48.460 INFO - Java: Sun Microsystems Inc. 16.3-b01
11:15:48.462 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.logVersionNumber(SeleniumServer.java:275
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.logStartupInfo(SeleniumServer.java:678)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.<init>(SeleniumServer.java:229)
        at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.main(SeleniumServer.java:200)
        at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(GridLauncher.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
        at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.internal.BuildInfo.loadBuildProperties(BuildInfo.java:46)
        at org.openqa.selenium.internal.BuildInfo.<clinit>(BuildInfo.java:38)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: Is that a Samba share?  If so, what happens when you try `'smb://my-remote-computer-name/...'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I did a lot of tests, changing paths and parameters... and I figure out that:

Under Windows 7 I cannot run *Command Prompt* locally to call `java` command calling this selenium server jar which by its turn is in another computer.

I had to put selenium server's jar in the same computer:

```
java -jar C:\temp\selenium-server-2.5.0\selenium-server-standalone-2.5.0.jar
```

Doing this, the java exception is gone.